# Customizing enumerated lists with tikz prints enumi instead of number

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, lists, enumerate

I'm trying to make an `enumerate` list that has the numbers inside a colored circle. For the circles I'm using the `tikz` package and the `color` package. I define a circle in the preamble and then I redefine the list items:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}

% Defining the circle:
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
    \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt,fill=lightgray,lightgray] (char) {\color{gray}\textbf#1};}}

% Redefining the list items
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\protect\circled{enumi}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
 \item foo
 \item bar
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

The problem is that instead of printing the list numbers, it just prints an `enumi`. I'm following the Wikibooks on [customizing enumerated lists](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/List_Structures#Customizing_enumerated_lists). I think there should be a way to make it work without adding extra packages, but I don't know how.

If it is not through `enumi`, **how should I access the number of the list**?

Cheers!

Comment: Maybe `\protect\circled{\arabic{enumi}}` works?

Comment: @egreg Oh, so it was the `\arabic`! It worked =). However I'm getting a warning: `** WARNING ** Unable to read OpenType/TrueType Unicode cmap table.` and `** WARNING ** Failed to load ToUnicode CMap for font "Alegreya-Black"`

Comment: I see no such warning if I add `\usepackage{Alegreya}`. Your example shows no trace of using that font, so I can't say more. But it's certainly not connected with the present problem.

Comment: @egreg Oh my, you're right. Sorry! (it's past midnight and I'm a bit tired, he he)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should *not* say `\textbf#1`, but `\bfseries#1` or `\textbf{#1}`. Also it should be `\arabic{enumi}`, not `enumi`: with your code you're passing `enumi` to `\circled` as `#1`, not the instruction that prints the value of the counter.

However I suggest using `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumitem}

% Defining the circle:
\DeclareRobustCommand*\circled[1]{%
  \tikz[
    baseline=(char.base)
  ]{%
    \node[
      shape=circle,
      draw,
      inner sep=2pt,
      fill=lightgray,
      lightgray
     ] (char) {\color{gray}\bfseries#1};%
   }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\circled{\arabic*},ref=\arabic*]
 \item foo
 \item bar
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

You can customize all first level `enumerate` environments to use `\circled` with

```
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\circled{\arabic*},ref=\arabic*}
```

in the preamble and you'll need no optional argument to `\begin{enumerate}`.

[image]

If you don't want extra packages, but I'm not sure why, then the method of redefining `\labelenumi` will work, provided it is

```
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\protect\circled{\arabic{enumi}}}
```

However remember that in the definition of `\circled` you ***must*** do either `\bfseries#1` or `\textbf{#1}`, because `\textbf#1` is wrong and will produce unscrutable errors.

Why should you want to load `enumitem`? Simple; if you do

```
\item\label{foo} text
```

and then try `\ref{foo}`, you'll get a circled number in text, which doesn't appear correct. With the code above using `enumitem`, `\ref{foo}` will just print an unadorned number.

Comment: Mmm... Your first comment had solved the problem already. I just had to add the `\arabic`. I prefer to avoid adding an extra package if I can achieve things natively. I'll accept the answer though. The colors are just easy ones, for the sake of testing. The document already has a defined palette and design =) Thank you!